# Mysql query using group_concat and self referencing id in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table and sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE `sections` (
  `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `parent_section_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`section_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `sections` (`section_id`, `name`, `parent_section_id`) VALUES
(1, 'City', NULL),
(2, 'Supplements', 4),
(3, 'News', 5),
(4, 'Sunday', 2),
(5, 'Monday', 2),
(6, 'Tuesday', 2),
(7, 'Wednesday', 2),
(8, 'Thursday', 2),
(9, 'Friday', 2),
(10, 'Saturday', 2),
(11, 'Home', 4),
(12, 'Games', 4),
(13, 'Sites', 5),
(14, 'Sports', 5),
(15, 'Cyber Space', 6);
```

parent_section_id is foreign key referencing to section_id in the same table which can have null if it doesn't belong to any other section.

How can I get the below output I have tried using group_concat function but it doesn't give the exact result. The parent_section_id is pointing to id from the same table. Should I use any other column to achieve the below output or use some other table to keep track of Sections which contains sub sections.
Please help me solve this problem or suggest any other approach

```
id, Name, SubSections
----------------------
1, 'City', null
2, 'Supplements', 'Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday'
3, 'News', null
4, 'Sunday', 'Homes,Games'
5, 'Monday','Sites,Sports'
6, 'Tuesday', 'Cyber Space'
7, 'Wednesday', null
8, 'Thursday', null
9, 'Friday', null
10, 'Saturday', null
11, 'Home', null
12, 'Games', null
13, 'Site', null
14, 'Sports', null
15, 'Cyber Space',null
```

Here is sql fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9767/2

Final Query

```
select s1.section_id, s1.name, group_concat(s2.name) as subsections,
(select name from sections where section_id = s1.parent_section_id) as 'parentname'
from sections s1
left join sections s2 on s1.section_id = s2.parent_section_id
group by s1.section_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you want by using a (left) self-join on  `section_id = parent_section_id` like so:

```
select s1.section_id, s1.name, group_concat(s2.name) as subsections
from sections s1
left join sections s2 on s1.section_id = s2.parent_section_id
group by s1.section_id;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9767/4)

Comment: Thanks for your time it solved my issue. Just a quick question is it possible to indicate Sunday's parent is Supplements, Home's parent is Sunday, Sites parent is Monday and so on. But Supplements doesn't have any parent.

Comment: @Sharath I think you would need an additional join for each level in the hierarchy, or maybe use some dynamic sql solution. In any case I would think that it's better to ask this as a separate question as it might require more knowledge about MySQL than I have, and if you post a new question you'll expose it to more people.